# Rails get id of new record created in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have `jobplans` that have many `jobtasks`.  These are like templates.  I want to create `workorders` and `tasks` from them.

This is the code in the `jobplans` controller:

```
def copy_to_workorder
  @jobplan = Jobplan.find(params[:id]) # find original jobplan
  wo_attrs =  @jobplan.attributes
  wo_attrs.delete('woschedule_id')
  Workorder.create(wo_attrs)

  @jobplan.jobtasks.each do |jobtask|
    jobtask_attrs = jobtask.attributes
    jobtask_attrs.delete('jobplan_id')
    jobtask_attrs.merge!({ workorder_id: @workorder.id })
    Task.create(jobtask_attrs)
  end

  redirect_to @jobplan, notice: 'Project was successfully created.'
end
```

My problem is the `@workorder` is nil.  I need each new `task` to refer to the `workorder`. How do access the id for the newly created `workorder`?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this:

```
def copy_to_workorder
  @jobplan = Jobplan.find(params[:id]) # find original jobplan
  wo_attrs =  @jobplan.attributes
  wo_attrs.delete('woschedule_id')
  workorder = Workorder.create(wo_attrs)
  # ^^^^^ saving the newly created record in a local variable
  #       so we can refer to it later

  @jobplan.jobtasks.each do |jobtask|
    jobtask_attrs = jobtask.attributes
    jobtask_attrs.delete('jobplan_id')
    jobtask_attrs.merge!(workorder_id: workorder.id)
    #                                  ^^^^^^ now fetch its id
    Task.create(jobtask_attrs)
  end

  redirect_to @jobplan, notice: 'Project was successfully created.'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You're never instantiating `@workorder` (and you don't really need an instance variable). Just change:

```
 Workorder.create(wo_attrs)
```

to

```
 workorder = Workorder.create(wo_attrs)
```

and further on

```
jobtask_attrs.merge!({ workorder_id: workorder.id })
```

GL & HF

Comment: Wow, you beat me to it @Agis.